# Elasticsearh nested query - custom scoring

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to see if i can find all the records whose age value is not null - boost them by 1000 else find all the records whose age value is null, then find only those records with censusyear greater than 1910

```
GET _search
{
 "size":20, 
  "from":0, 
  "query" : {
      "custom_filters_score": {
         "query": {
         "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "or":  [
                {"query":{"field": { "Age": "exists"}}},
                { "and":[
                    {"query":{"field": { "Age" : null}}},
                    {"range":{"CensusYear": {"gte":1910}}}
                    ]
                   }]
            }
         }
         },
         "filters": [
            {
               "filter": {"term":{"Age":"exists"}}, "boost":"1000"
            }
         ]
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: any more information about what version of Elasticsearch you're running? Seeing any errors? Is "rane" a typo when you've copied it over or an actual typo in your code?

Comment: its version 1. something (i think the latest one). Its range and not rane. .. let me corret the typo

Comment: OK, thanks for replying, what data are you getting back from this query currently?

Comment: I think i have figured that out. Can you please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773276/elasticsearch-scoring-on-bool-query