# elasticsearch scoring on bool query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a nested query for bool condition in this format

```
GET _search 
{
    "explain": true, 
   "from": 1,
   "size": 10,
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "function_score": {
               "boost": 1,
               "score_mode": "sum",
               "boost_mode": "sum",
               "functions": [],
               "query": {
                  "bool": {
                     "must": [
                        {
                           "bool": {
                              "should": [
                                 {
                                    cond1.0
                                 },
                                 {
                                    cond1.1
                                 },
                                 {
                                   cond1.2
                                 }
                              ] , "minimum_number_should_match": 1, "boost": 5.0
                           }
                        }
                     ] ,
                     "should": [
                        {
                           "bool": {
                              "should": [
                                 {
                                    cond2.0
                                 },
                                 {
                                   cond 2.1

                                 },
                                 {
                                    cond 2.2
                                 }
                              ] , "minimum_number_should_match": 1, "boost":3.0
                           }
                        }

                     ],
                     "minimum_number_should_match": 1
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "fields": [
      "*"
   ]
}
```

So the boost of 5.0 if changed to 4.0, should ideally impace just the boolean conditions of 1.0,1.1,1.2 but it also seems to have an effect on the score of 2.0,2.1,2.2. I dont understand how that should happen. Shouldnt it be mutually exclusive

Comment: any news? did you solved it?

Comment: if you could provide the actual field names in the query, it would be more informative. Maybe the docs that are appearing in the results are matching in both the sections of your query (1.x and 2.x conditions)